# String includes returning false, then converting string with toString() returns [Object object]

Tags: javascript

I'm getting crazy behind this thing, so please make me get out of this madness.

I get a string (verified with `typeof`) that I name 'basevalue'.

The original verified string shows this: `{ data: [ { id: '201010', type: 'question' } ] }`

Now I want to check the ID with:

```
if (basevalue.includes("201010")) { 
  var result = "TRUE"; 
}
```

or

```
if (basevalue.includes("{ data: [{ id: '201010', type: 'question' }] }")) {
  var result = "TRUE"; 
}
```

It **never** gets to "TRUE".

Then I thought to re-convert it to a string with toString();
So:

```
var newvalue = basevalue.toString()
```

result: `[ Object object ]`

How can I check if this string contains the value '201010'?

UPDATE.

I found out that data is an array.

So the value "201010" is contained in: data[0].id (it seems that data is an array).

Now the problem is counting how much data[number] exists, and how to check if "201010" is contained in all of ids

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: **If** `baseValue` were really the string shown, `basevalue.includes("201010")` would be true. So either A) `baseValue` isn't that string, or B) It is, and your code isn't interpreting the fact that `basevalue.includes("201010")` is true correctly. We can't help you know which, you'll have to debug it.

Comment: @SethLutske - Just FWIW, code fences use three backticks, not four.

Comment: Wow I've been using 4 forever.  Learn something new every day.

Comment: @Mark - please put this simple code into [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) - you will discover that whatever is stored in `basevalue` is not a string at all.

Comment: @SethLutske - We do if we're lucky. ;-) Great stuff helping the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe according to your edit you should run something like this to get all elements your data array that match the string '201010':

```
const allMatches = data.filter(e => e.id === '201010');
console.log('Found these many 201010:', allMatches.length);
```

Or do you specifically need to work with strings?

Comment: I guess my snippet fills your needs, then :)

Answer (score -1):

If basevalue is really that string it works. Maybe it's not.

```js
var basevalue = "{ data: [{ id: '201010', type: 'question' }] }";
if (basevalue.includes("{ data: [{ id: '201010', type: 'question' }] }")) {
  var result = "TRUE";
}

console.log(result)
```